# How to install Spyder3?

Tags: software-installation, spyder

I'm looking for instructions on how to download and install **Spyder3**.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and these are my computer specifications:

- Ubuntu 64bits
- Lenovo 510 Core I7
- Ram: 8gb

Answer (score 14):

Spyder can be installed with the following commands:

**Spyder**

```
sudo apt install spyder
```

**Spyder3**

```
sudo apt install spyder3
```

Python IDE for scientists
Spyder is a free open-source Python development environment providing MATLAB-like features in a simple and lightweight application.

If for you want to install the latest version of Sypder 3 instead of the Ubuntu package maintainer's version in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier, the commands to do so are as follows:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit  
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade spyder
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later the commands to install the latest version of Sypder 3 are:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit  
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade spyder
```

Spyder can do inline plotting. To try out this feature open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-matplotlib spyder3 ipython3
```

After the ipython3 prompt in the IPython console copy/paste the below code and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to run it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
x, y = [-1, 12], [1, 4]  
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Later in time it become just spyder3, so : sudo apt-get install spyder3

Comment: @Omegafil spyder and spyder3 are two separate apps in all versions of Ubuntu from 12.04-19.04. You can install either one or both.

Answer (score 2):

Spyder3 is only available for trusty from backports repository.

1. Open `software-properties-gtk` → Update tab → Enable "*Unsupported updates (trusty-backports)*"
2. On closing, reload package list.

Now, you will able to find it in the software-center, otherwise using command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install spyder3
```

For similar issues, you may search for packages through [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)